# JS/Jquery - как поменять в URL GET-параметр при выборе значений радио кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно при выборе значений радио кнопки менять значение GET-параметра?
На странице выводится ссылка , в нее передаются Get-параметры action.php?p=1 , мне нужно при выборе значений radio button менять параметр p=2
Проблема в том, что сам url формируется из PHP, и в нем присутствуют другие параметры, т.е желательно менять именно в самой ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать два объекта [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL), чтобы получить доступ к параметрам и [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), чтобы изменить один из них. Ваш код может выглядеть как-то так (я его не запускал, могут быть ошибки, но идея будет понятна) ...

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("input[name='param']").click(function () {
            var checkedVaule = $(this).val(),
                currentUrl = new URL($("#actionUrl").attr("href")),
                params = new URLSearchParams(currentUrl.search);
            params.set('p', checkedVaule);
            currentUrl.search = params;
            $("#actionUrl").attr("href", currentUrl.toString())
        });
    });
</script>

// ...

<input type="radio" name="param" value="1"/> One
<input type="radio" name="param" value="2"/> Two
<input type="radio" name="param" value="3"/> Three

// ...

<a id="actionUrl" href="action.php?p=1&otherParam=test">Link</a>
```

Пожалуйста замете совместимость броузера, IE не работает.